# Django - looking for architectural advice for my project

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

First of all, I want to say that I'm really a novice with Django, and looking for some architectural advice for my project.

I have a front-end template that looks like this:
[image]

When a user clicks "Save" button, the information in the input fields needs to be saved into the database. I don't want my page to be refreshed when I click "Save" button, because only the information that belongs to the section will be sent. (however, if this needs some AJAX plugin, I can give it up on that for now. Primary importance for now is just connecting this front-end with PostgreSQL database)

Ex: clicking Save in "Overall BHA" section will only save inputs in the "Overall BHA" into the database without refreshing the page. And the same process for "Drill Bit" section too.

First, I need advice on models.py

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class BHA_overall(models.Model):
    drill_str_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    depth_in = models.IntegerField()
    depth_out = models.IntegerField()
    drilled = models.IntegerField()
    # .......

class BHA_drill_bit(models.Model):

    BIT_OPTIONS = ( ('PDC Drag'), ('Roller Cone'), ('other'))
    color = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=BIT_OPTIONS, default='other')
    size = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    wob_max = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    # .......
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve my goal. Both "Overall BHA" and "Drill Bits" are part of the data called "BHA". Since both of these will be loaded on the same page, I'm not sure if I want to completely separate these two. Maybe I should create a container class called "BHA" and make "BHA_overall" & "BHA_drill_bit" a sub-class of it??

The above screenshot is just one page called BHA, but there are many other pages that have multiple sections within themselves. Any suggestions?

**views.py**

```
class BhaCreateView(CreateView):
    model = models.BHA_overall
    fields = '__all__'
    context_object_name = 'BHA_overall'
    template_name = 'base/bha.html'
```

This just a really rough code that I made just ask a question here. 
I'm aware that there are many kind of class-based-views, such as DetailView, ListView, CreateView, UpdateView... and many more. Which one, or ones should I use for my purpose? I'm thinking that I need some combination of CreateView and UpdateView, since the users will be updating new information to BHA section, but there still are chances that information was not inserted in the first place at all.

How should I do this?

Comment: If you want this page not refresh,i'm be afraid of you need to use ajax and djangorestframework to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if you want to save data to the database while not refreshing the page, you only need to implement AJAX which is not hard at all (I do it a ton). In terms of your architecture, if everything in the model is directly related to BHA then it wil be better off to have it inside of it, unless you need some of that information to be used/accessed individually of it or the information will be duplicated across multiple instances. As an example, let's say I have an invoice system that has invoices and customers. I could have the customer info directly part of the invoice model, but I can have many invoices with the same customer....so, it would be better to have many invoices with the same customer info reference the same customer information. This is handled through a Foreign Key. Also think about queries and how having 2 models needed for this "set" of information you need to get. Now you will probably have a join on the query when there is no need for that to be happening. This is why I recommend you put them in the same model, until you realize a need to separate them.

Last but not least, if you are new to Django, i would recommend not using CBV (Class Based Views). There is too much magic going on to understand what you are doing (many tutorials spend a lot of time on CBV and personally I am not a fan). Go with FBV (Function Based Views), since you will know exactly what you are doing even if it gets a little messy or more lines of code. To put this into perspective, about 10 months ago I started developing an invoicing system Django project knowing nothing. I began using CBV and instantly switched to FBV. I now have a multi-tenant production app running on Heroku as a nearly complete invoicing system.

Since you are new, I am sure this will help you explore how you want to develop your app. It all comes down to trying something and gradually changing it to what you want. It may be good to screw up your models and db like I did in the beginning because then you get to learn how to make massive data migrations along with schema changes. Hope this helps!